# Packaging a flat jar, containing some dependencies, with some folders outside of the jar, in maven

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm trying to package a file structure one such as this:

```
config/
images/
app.jar/
    |-some_dependency/
    |-another_dependency/
    |-classes/
    \-META-INF/
```

*some_dependency* and *another_dependency* being some unpacked jar libraries.

How can I do this? I can do one or the other with the assembly plugin. Can I do the above?

Comment: Simple answer. Yes this can be achieved with maven-assembly-plugin.

Comment: @khmarbaise Well... I've tried to make it work! Seriously, it'll be a long post if I start listing everything I've tried. I've tried playing around with the assembly and shade plugin.

Answer (score 1):

If just additiontal folder required, maven-resource-plugin can be used: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html

For include all dependencies in one jar file, "maven-assembly-plugin" can be used:

```
 <plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: :D well that's what I've been asking. How do you do it at the same time?